# How do I create a list of all occurances of a string which ends with a specific file type found in a text file?

Tags: python, arrays, parsing, text, find

I'm trying to extract all of the links to image files from a text file.  All of the image files end in either .jpg or .gif, and are surrounded by quotation marks.  I want to find the first occurrence of .jpg or .gif, and then copy all of the characters between the first quotation mark located before .jpg (or .gif) and the first quotation mark found after .jpg (or.gif).  Then I want to add this link to an array or to another text file, and repeat the process for every instance of .jpg or .gif in the original text file.

Here's an example of what the text file might look like:

```
d/scriript type="texft/javascript">
    $(document).fready(function () {
        $('#post-contfainer-1720130 .post-assets .thumb A').lightBox({
            txtImafge:      'Image',
            txtOf:          'of',
            overflayOpacity:    0       });
<div class="thumb"><a href""="#">="**https://imaginepilgrimages.com/asset/image/resize/2/32/32/1/c331065jt99875146b0a1fg9140.jpg**"riript type="texft/javascript">
    $(document).freadriript type="texft/javascript">
    $(document).fread
d/scriript type="texft/javascript">
    $(document).fready(function () {
        $('#post-contfainer-1720130 .post-assets .thumb A').lightBox({
            txtImafge:      'Image',
            txtOf:          'of',
            overflayOpacity:    0       });
<div class="thumb"><a href""="#">="**https://imaginepilgrimages.com/asset/image/resize/2/32/32/75146b0a1fg9140.gif**"riript type="texft/javascript">
    $(document).freadriript type="texft/javascript">
    $(document).fread
d/scriript type="texft/javascript">
    $(document).fready(function () {
        $('#post-contfainer-1720130 .post-assets .thumb A').lightBox({
            txtImafge:      'Image',
            txtOf:          'of',
            overflayOpacity:    0       });
<div class="thumb"><a href""="#">="https://imaginepilgrimages.com/asset/image/resize/2/32/32/1/c331065jt99fgfgage55h6u7rrth6875146b0a1fg9140.jpg"riript type="texft/javascript">
    $(document).freadriript type="texft/javascript">
    $(document).fread
```

I've just started using python and I've been stuck on this for a while.  Can anybody help me with this?  Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? Stack overflow is not a place to get others to do it for you.

Comment: How do you want to handle the leading '**'?  Your post seems like you want to remove the trailing ones -- it would make sense to remove the leading ones as well, but detecting those is a little tricky if the format isn't fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
re.findall('"([^"]*\.(?:gif|jpg)[^"]*)"', text)
```

Don't expect it to be particularly flexible or robust; for that you'd probably want an actual parser.

Comment: @mgilson, this has officially become eerie.

Comment: At least we switched the order of 'jpg' and 'gif' ... Nobody could accuse us of plagiarism now!

Comment: @mgilson, and you had to go and one-up me by offering exposition. For shame.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the image filenames, except that it doesn't attempt to trim off the leading/trailing '**'

```
import re
images=[]
with open('test.dat') as f:
   for line in f:
      images.extend(re.findall(r'"([^"]*\.(?:jpg|gif)[^"]*)"',line))
```

The regular expression looks for a quotation mark and then grabs anything that isn't a quotation mark specifically checking to make sure that '.jpg' or '.gif' are in the string.

Comment: great minds think alike, and apparently post simultaneously, to within a tolerance of milliseconds. :)